# How may I replace multiple delimited strings of a line non-greedily?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to generate riddles from accordingly formatted input strings.

Example input:
`Foo was the +first+ to get a drink at +the bar+.`

Desired output:
`Foo was the _____ to get a drink at ___ ___.`

**With any standard shell tool, what's the simplest (on the eye) solution for this?**

Answer (score 5):

This awk one-liner should help you:

```
awk -F'+' -v OFS="" 'NF>2{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)gsub(/\S/,"_",$i)}7'
```

Test

```
kent$  awk -F'+' -v OFS="" 'NF>2{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)gsub(/\S/,"_",$i)}7' <<<"Foo was the +first+ to get a drink at +the bar+."
Foo was the _____ to get a drink at ___ ___.
```

Comment: This is actually nicer than mine for sure and easier on the eye.  As an aside: Though unspecified in the question (and probably completely irrelevant here) but yours and mine give different output for edge cases and malformed strings, such as "X++Y" and "X+++Y".

Comment: What is the purpose of `7` at the end? Without it, no output prints but I couldn't understand its purpose.

Comment: @Utku non-zero number will do default action : print in awk. 7, 1, 100, 1000 in this case do the same

Answer (score 1):

Your "easy on the eye" test may get ... strained by the answers to this question.

Perl:

```
$ echo "$str" | perl -pe 's/\+(.*?)\+/ ($new=$1) =~ s{\w}{_}g; $new /eg'
Foo was the _____ to get a drink at ___ ___.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but ain't especially pretty:

```
sed -r ':a;/\+[^+]*\+/!b;s//\n&\n/;h;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;s/\+([^+]*)\+/\1/g;s/[^ ]/_/g;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ta'
```

like this:

```
$ echo "Foo was the +first+ to get a drink at +the bar+." | sed -r ':a;/\+[^+]*\+/!b;s//\n&\n/;h;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;s/\+([^+]*)\+/\1/g;s/[^ ]/_/g;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ta'
Foo was the _______ to get a drink at ____ ____.
```

Basicly 'stolen' from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014707/1061997